# How to use If statement as loop in C Programming?

Tags: c

I want to use If statement as loop, I am trying to write a program which should keep on getting input until user input 0, As user input 0, it should terminate and give sum of all entered numbers as output. For example:
Please enter value of N
1
4
5
0
Sum is=10

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n=0;
    int sum;
   printf("Enter Value of n");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   if(n!=0)
   {
      sum=sum+n;
   }
   else
        printf("Sum is = %d", sum);

  }
```

Program terminates after getting first input, ideally it should keep on getting input until 0 is entered. And then it should print sum of all entered values.

Comment: how we will use while here.

Comment: Of topic: Always check the value returned by `scanf`

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line before asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: It can be possible, using "goto" statement.

Comment: And do you have a `goto` in your code? An `if` is not and cannot be a loop. An `if` followed by a `goto` *can* make a loop, but just because it's possible doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An if statement is not a loop and will never be a loop. Sounds like you want a while loop.

```
int main()
{
   int n=0;
   int sum = 0, counter;
   int aver;
   printf("Enter Value of n");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   while(n != 0)
   {
      sum=sum+n;
      printf("Enter Value of n");
      scanf("%d",&n);
   }
   printf("Sum is = %d", sum);
  }
```

This could be simplified even more using a "do while"

```
int main()
{
   int n=1;
   int sum = 0;

   do {
       printf("Enter Value of n");
       scanf("%d",&n);
       sum=sum+n;
   }
   while(n != 0)
   printf("Sum is = %d", sum);
  }
```

Comment: @4386427 True - I just copied OPs code and didn't analyze further. Fixed now. I've also removed unused vars from the "do while" example

Comment: Thank you for help, we can use if as loop by adding "goto" statement.

Comment: @UmarFarooq No. Just no. The tool for your job is a `do while`. You should not even bother to learn C's `goto` syntax!

Answer (score 1):

You need a do-while loop

```
sum = 0;
do
{
    printf("Enter Value of n"); 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    sum+=n;
 } 
 while(n!=0);
 printf("Sum is = %d", sum);
```

Note: In do-while loop, your loop block gets executed without checking the condition, after the end of loop block it checks for condition and breaks the loop.

So at first the code asks for input, sums the number and then check for 0 input. If so, then breaks the loop and prints the value of sum, else it again executes the loop block.

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible using `goto` statement, following is code

```
int main()
{
   int n, add;
   Sum:
   add=add+n;
   printf("Enter number:");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   //add=add+n;
   if(n!=0)
        goto Sum;
   else

       printf("sum is =%d",add);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum1 =0;
int sum();
int main()
{
  sum(); 
}
int sum(){
   int n;
   printf("Enter number :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
   if(n!=0){
      sum1=sum1+n;
      sum();
   }
   else{
     printf("Sum :%d\n",sum1);
  }
}
```